# Importing classes not working. "Unable to compile class for JSP"

Tags: java, tomcat

I know that this is a common question. I tried every solution so far, but nothing is working (or I just did it not correctly).

[this is the error](https://puu.sh/t8wIP/938c8c7843.png)

[here is my file hierarchy](https://puu.sh/t8wNV/6606b4385c.png)

The `.java` files are all in a package called `business_logic`

Here is the code:

```
<%@ page import="business_logic.*" %>
<%
LicenseManagement.ini();
String F_name = LicenseManagement.myUser.getName();
%>
<nav class="nav">

<h3>Menue</h3>
<p><b>You are logged in as:</b></p>
<p>F_name, L_name</p>
<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>
<br>
<br>
<p><b>User Menue</b></p>
<ul>

    <li><a href="dashboard.jsp">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="mylicenses.jsp">My Licenses</a></li>
    <li><a href="requestlicense.jsp">Request License</a></li>

</ul>

<%
if (!(session.getAttribute("admin") == null) ||     (session.getAttribute("admin") == "")) {
%>
<br>
<p><b>Admin Menue</b></p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="newprogram.jsp">New Program</a></li>
    <li><a href="newlicense.jsp">New License</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Whats wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the screen shot of your file hierarchy, you have include the source code for the imported files in the `classes` tree.  You should include the `.class` files instead.

The JSP compiler assumes that all imported classes have already been compiled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Iam using IntelliJ and i dont find the .class files. I know that i can compile them via command line. But do i really need to do that every time i updated my code?

Answer (score 0):

The place where you are keeping your `.java` files doesn't seem right.

Generally, Java source files are kept outside the `WEB-INF` folder. Only the compiled `.class` files are placed in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder as per the package hierarchy of your classes.

Place the compiled classes in the `WEB-INF/classes` and your Error should go away.

> **Update**

I found this screenshot on the web. Take a look and see if you can figure out the path by comparing with your project structure.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: how do i get the .class files automaticly placed into the right folder? Right now i need to compile them via command line and move the class into the right folder.  

I guess there is a better way to do this. Iam using intellij

Comment: I've not used IntelliJ. In Eclipse, web projects create a `WebContent` fodler for JSPs and a `src` folder outside WebContent for Java source files. These Java files in `srs` are compiled and the class files are moved automatically by Eclipse to the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. I'm not sure about the hierarchy of IntelliJ folder structure.